# Action bar styling issues

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I need to add a dropdown list into an action bar. I tried a lot of different ways of doing this, but every one demonstrates its specific flaw. Here is the results of 2 of the attempts.

[image]

The upper is a spinner, added into the action bar by means of `actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);`. No styles is used except for entire application theme, which is `@style/Theme.Sherlock`. (The application must look uniformely on new and old devices, so ActionBarSherlock is used.) As you may see, this method produces black text color on dark/black background. A selected element is "shown" in action bar in black font over black background. (By default it was `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` and `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` layouts, but I tried custom ones with references to different available styles as well).

For example:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, test);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, new ActionBar.OnNavigationListener()
...
```

The second is a menu. It looks ok in regard to colors. I'd like to have the same style (colors, font size, alignment) in the spinner. But I can't get this after playing with a lot of suggestions found on Internet, and on SO particularly. Please note, that I do not want to specify a hardcoded colors in my custom style. I want to inherit them from existing styles (system or Sherlock's holo themes). And parent styles should be known on API level 10. Anyway, these IS the acceptable style for menus. I only need to move it to the spinner.

The menu approach could be a workaround as is, but it lacks the little trianle in the bottom right corner, indicating that a dropdown will be presented to a user. I know it comes from the spinner state list drawable, and I can apply the same background to menu items. But, it affects ALL menu items, whereas I need only to show the triangle on items with submenu.

I'd appreciate a solution in either direction.

Comment: confuz.. what you want...??

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar, I need a dropdown in readable colors (for example, light color on dark background, where the "light" and "dark" come from standard theme), with the indicator that the dropdown is avalable.

Comment: Post the code where you init the adapter used in the navigation list.

Comment: As Context passed to the ArrayAdapter constructor try `Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();` instead of `this`.

Comment: @rciovati, Tried. Did not help.

Comment: Is this sample working for you? http://bit.ly/ZIXyda

Comment: @rciovati, yes, after changing the spinner layouts to `R.layout.sherlock.`, I got it working. Post the answer.

Comment: FWIW, i have this same issue using the action-bar implementation in the appcompat support library (instead of ActionBarSherlock). Unfortunately, no R.layout.sherlock_ resources to fall back to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code from the samples:

```
    mLocations = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.locations);

    Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.locations, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
    list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);

    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);
```

Took from: http://bit.ly/19mJdLK

Comment: Thanks for the answer. BTW, I don't see an example on using a spinner as action view (`android:actionLayout`), but even with themed context and sherlock's layouts, the spinner is not styled there anyhow, that is it displayed as a standard spinner. Is there another hint for this?